# Ctrl + Click on dataframe name to view it not working

Tags: r, rstudio

I know normally if I ctrl + click a data frame's name it'll automatically run the code "View()" but I just installed a fresh copy of Rstudio* on my PC and this doesn't seem to work. What am I missing?

Not sure if there's meant to be a package or something that does this?

Comment: I think that's a feature of Rstudio or another IDE, not base R?

Comment: RStudio 2023.03.1 Build 446, Ctrl+click and F2 works fine to `View`.

Comment: Problems with the Posit/RStudio IDE are on-topic here, however I think you will get much better help at their [community forums](https://community.rstudio.com/).

Comment: Oh I am using R studios.